# Passing a csv.NewWriter() to another func in Golang to Write to file Asynchronously

Tags: csv, go

I am making API calls (potentially thousands in a single job) and as they return and complete, I'd like to be able to write them to a single shared file (say CSV for simplicity) instead of waiting for all of them to complete before writing.

How could I share a single `csv.Writer()` in a way that effectively writes to a single file shared by many threads. This may be too daunting of a task, but I was curious if there was a way to go about it.

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "os"
)

type Row struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
}

func main () {
    file, _ := os.Create("file.csv")
    w := csv.NewWriter(file)

    // Some operations to create a slice of Row structs that will contain the rows 
    // To write
    var rowsToWrite []Row
    // Now lets iterate over and write to file
    // Ideally, I'd like to do this in a goroutine but not entirely sure about thread safe writes
    for _, r := range rowsToWrite {
        go func(row, writer) {
            err := writeToFile(row, writer)
            if err != nil {
            // Handle error
            }
        }(r, w)
    }

}

func writeToFile(row Row, writer ???) error {

    // Use the shared writer to maintain where I am at in the file so I can append to the CSV
    if err := w.Write(row); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil

}
```

Comment: Since this problem sounds a bit silly, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? If there are separate processes, then they will append independently. In a single process (like the example) writing each row in a separate goroutine will cause changes in order.

Comment: I suggest looking at channels as means of communication between threads, I'm not sure if sharing the same writer is thread-safe. But, again, if they are separate _processes_ then you aren't sharing anything between threads.

Comment: @maksimov order doesn't matter. I'm simply reading from an API, taking the response and writing to a shared CSV so that I can later load it via Snowflake.

Comment: Do you _really_ mean "between processes?"  If yes, then this is less of a go issue and more of an OS/platform one - is it a *nix-like system with various IPC constructs available?  Do you care about locking the file?  Etc.    By "less of a go issue" I mean, you need to decide how you want to coordinate between the processes - obviously, you would then need to implement whatever you choose.  But I think you need to provide more details about your use case here, because the language you've used is not consistent - "shared funcs" do not apply between separate processes.

Comment: @SandyCash if I create a goroutine, my understanding is that it spawns a small thread to perform a ```process``` or task. I would like the result of that process or task to write to a shared file (namely a CSV). I am asking how to safely approach this problem asynchronously so I do not have to necessarily wait for each result to return and write everything as a large batch of data in memory. As a thread completes, I'd like to write to the file with a lock, then unlock it for the next process that has completed to append to the same file.

Comment: Can you clarify what "shared" means... and specifically what "shared between different processes" means? By process do you mean "go routine"? Please edit your question to give us a better idea of what you're actually trying to accomplish, and what the constraints are that require multiple _processes_. Right now, from everything I've read, I don't see what's stopping you from getting the API response, parsing individual objects, holding all the objects in a single slice, then iterating that slice of objects as you write them to  a CSV. That would certainly be the easiest to get right.

Comment: @ZachYoung If I have to make thousands of API calls, I'd rather not continue to hold them in a single slice in memory, waiting until all are complete to write to file. The idea would be to asynchronously write to a single shared file AS each API call is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of back and forth on this one for me

I originally thought you could use the Write() method on a csv.Writer in a goroutine, but there are issues when the buffer flushes to disk as the buffer is being written to... not exactly sure.

Anyways, to get back to what you were originally asking for...

Still using the same setup to download Todo objects from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, as an example:

```golang
type Todo struct {
    UserID    int    `json:"userId"`
    ID        int    `json:"id"`
    Title     string `json:"title"`
    Completed bool   `json:"completed"`
}

// toRecord converts Todo struct to []string, for writing to CSV.
func (t Todo) toRecord() []string {
    userID := strconv.Itoa(t.UserID)
    id := strconv.Itoa(t.ID)
    completed := strconv.FormatBool(t.Completed)

    return []string{userID, id, t.Title, completed}
}

// getTodo gets endpoint and unmarshalls the response JSON into todo.
func getTodo(endpoint string) (todo Todo) {
    resp, err := http.Get(endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&todo)
    return
}
```

The following:

- Will start one "parent" goroutine to start filling the `todos` channel:

  - inside that routine, goroutines will be started for each HTTP request and will send the response Todo on `todos`
  - the parent will wait till all the request routines are done
  - when they're done, the parent will close the `todos` channel
- Meanwhile, main has moved on and is ranging over `todos`, picking a Todo off one-at-a-time and writing it to the CSV.
- When the original, "parent" goroutine finally closes `todos`, the for-loop will break, the writer does a final Flush(), and the program will complete.

```golang
func main() {
    todos := make(chan Todo)

    go func() {
        const nAPICalls = 200
        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        wg.Add(nAPICalls)
        for i := 0; i < nAPICalls; i++ {
            s := fmt.Sprintf("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/%d", i+1)

            go func(x string) {
                todos <- getTodo(x)
                wg.Done()
            }(s)
        }
        wg.Wait()

        close(todos)
    }()

    w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    w.Write([]string{"UserID", "ID", "Title", "Completed"})
    for todo := range todos {
        w.Write(todo.toRecord())
    }
    w.Flush()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is an excellent answer. However, my only issue that I fear is that I am dealing with some IoT data of very large volume. Potentially 20M rows of data per 1 day of load. It only takes ~5-10 minutes to pull that volume of data but the memory it consumes is quite large. Thats why I'd like to write it somewhere on disk rather than maintain it in memory. Hence the idea of sending the data to a channel for writing concurrently.

Comment: @Coldchain9, added update to stream results to CSV

Comment: Thanks for updating. I think the code you presented mentally makes sense to me. I guess I'll have to try it out in practice and see if there are any issues if I send potentially 50-100 threads and try to write to a single file. My other question was attempting to write each response to its own file in order to alleviate any issues of threads writing to a single file. Order doesn't matter, as long as the results are all stored on disk vs maintained in memory.

Comment: @Coldchain9, there are issues with calling Write() from individual goroutines... looks like the underlying buffer might be flushed to disk while another routine is writing to the buffer... not sure. Anyways, whole new approach, and maybe what you were **actually** asking for in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would (personally) not have the same file open for writing at two separate points in the code.  Depending on how the OS handles buffered writes, etc., you can end up with "interesting" things happening.

Given how you've described your goals, one might do something like (this is off the top of my head and not rigorously tested):

1. Create a channel to queue blocks of text (I assume) to be written - `make(chan []byte, depth)` - `depth` could be tuneable based on some tests you'd run, presumably.
2. Have a goroutine open a filehandle for writing on your file, then read from that queueing channel, writing whatever it gets from the channel to that file
3. you could then have *n* goroutines writing to the queueing channel, and as long as you don't exceed the channel capacity (outrun your ability to write), you might never need to worry about locks.

If you *did* want to use locks, then you'd need a [sync.Mutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex) shared between the goroutines responsible for enqueueing.

Season to taste, obviously.